# Using rabl and a collection, having trouble adding additional child node

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, rabl

I have a collection of articles I want to show in my json response.  I would also like to export a node about the type of json request asked.

## index.json.rabl

```
collection @articles => :headlines
extends 'articles/show'
```

## show.json.rabl

```
object @article
attributes :foo
```

So going to articles.json gives me:

```
 {"headlines":[{"foo":thing1},{"foo":thing2}]}
```

What I would like to do is get results like this:

```
{"rss":{"name":"articles","woot":"what?"},
{"headlines":[{"foo":thing1},{"foo":thing2}]}
```

I have tried putting node(:rss) { "yadda yadda" } in the index.json.rabl file, but that only adds the node :rss into the each article.

I tried using

```
 glue @article do
    node(:rss) { "yadda yadda" }
 end
```

in both the index and show files and neither worked as I was hoping.

I have tried numerous other things, but at this point I am only guess now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah... I figure it out.  I decided not to use "collection @articles"

## index.json.rabl

```
object false
node(:rss) { partial('articles/rss.json.rabl', :object => @feedName) }

node :headlines do
  partial(@jsonView, :object => @articles)
end
```

Comment: what is the @jsonView variable? I'm running into a similar problem.

Comment: Probably just a string that names which partial he wants to render (one with more or less detail for example), perhaps decided on some part of the query params. e.g. `/articles.json => @jsonView = "articles/light", /articles.json?detailed=true => @jsonView = "article/detailed"`